# What happens if you call but never ret?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm new to writing assembly (literally my first day), and I'm curious if there are any side effects to using `call` but then never using `ret`.

If there are no side effects, is it a bad practice to only ret sometimes?

The code bare-bones is something like:

```
my_func:
    call is_digit
    call is_lowercase
    jmp error

is_lowercase:
    cmp al, 'a'
    jb  isfalse
    cmp al, 'z'
    ja  isfalse
    jmp lowercase

is_digit:
    cmp al, '0'
    jb  isfalse
    cmp al, '9'
    ja  isfalse
    jmp digit

isfalse:
    ret

error:
    some stuff
```

Does it make sense in this context?

Comment: You properly should use `jmp` instead if you have no use for the return address.

Comment: In early days, yes end a `call` with `ret`. Later you might find reasons for other ways, but the important thing is to keep the stack balanced. Don't jump right back to where you came from without cleaning the return address off the stack, or you'll gradually run out of stack space.

Comment: @WeatherVane How do you clean the return address off the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will correctly jump to *error* if AL is neither a digit nor a lowercase.

If it is indeed a digit you jump to *digit* but **there** you should remove the return address from the stack. Use `add sp,2` if this is 16-bit code or use `add sp,4` if this is 32-bit code.
Alternatively insert this extra instruction **here** just before doing the `jmp`.

```
is_digit:
  cmp al, '0'
  jb  isfalse
  cmp al, '9'
  ja  isfalse
  add sp,2      ;Don't return from "call is_digit"
  jmp digit
```

All the previous applies also to how you work with *lowercase*.

If you got a register to spare (say DX) you can shorten the `add sp,2` to `pop dx`. Same goes for `add sp,4` to `pop edx`.

Comment: Does dx hold the return address? How does popping it clear the return of the stack?

Comment: DX will have the return address. Since `pop` effectively __removes__ it from the stack (by raising the stackpointer by 2) a subsequent `ret` would not be able to use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you control the program flow somehow. For example, you want to have an indefinite hang for some reason:

```
foo:
    jmp foo
    ret
```

There would be no point in adding `ret`, because it is not reached anyway.

Sure you don't need `ret`. You may also pop the return address from the stack and jump to it afterwards, which basically has the same result, but it's generally a good idea, because `ret` also kind of marks the end of a function.

Another way of implementing a function call could be this: Saving the return address in a register and then jumping to the register, when you need to. This would be, in fact, faster than the normal `ret`, because it does not use the slow stack, but is far more complex to read and understand.

Of course, you might argue whether or not assembly is actually meant to be readable at all ;-)

Comment: I updated the post with a little more specific details. Does it make sense what I'm trying to do?